# getting a source for <video src> in html from js script

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to display webms on my homepage in a random order
every time someone access the homepage.
I think, i got the random part done, my problem is,
getting the path string into the source src="" of my html code
my current take on this is:

HTML

```
<div class="window" id="videos" style="display: none;">
      <div class="content">
        <center>
          <video controls width="500">
            <source id="random_webm" src="" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 or .webm video, gramps.
          </video>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
function random_webm(max) {
var src = ["videos/ship.webm", "videos/ira.webm"];
 return random_webm.src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)];
src = rndwebm(3);
document.getElementById('random_webm').src = src.rndwebm(3); 

};
```

other things i tried
https://pastebin.com/raw/3Sjpd0gW

concluision - how it works now:

```
<div class="window" id="videos" style="display: none;">
      <div class="header">
        <img class="icon" src="images/video.png">
            gnu.3gp     
        <div class="buttons">
          <button id= "videos" title="minimize" class="window_content" onclick="videos() ">_</button>
          <button>◽</button>
          <button id= "videos" title="minimize" class="window_content" onclick="videos() ">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <center>
          <video controls width="500" id="random_webm" src="">
            <source type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 or .webm video, gramps.
          </video>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
function videos() {
  var src = ["videos/ship.webm", "videos/ira.webm"];
  document.getElementById('random_webm').src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)];

  var x = document.getElementById("videos");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

}

random_webm()
```

Comment: um is your js code correct .... anything after return will not be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, and adapt it to your needs.

```
function random_webm() {
  var src = ["videos/ship.webm", "videos/ira.webm"];
  document.getElementById('random_webm').src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)];
};

random_webm()
```

Comment: thanks it works, but instead of <source> i had to put the id and src in the <video> my code looks like this now `code <video controls width="500" id="random_webm" src="">
            <source id="random_webm" type="video/webm"> `